# Namespace no longer recognized after package update

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I've got a multi-project solution (VS2013 Express) and like an idiot I assumed that running `update-package` would only update the packages in the current project.

This caused all kinds of nastiness, the majority of which I've worked through and resolved. I'm now left with the following the MVC project and I'm stuck:

- the Default Namespace is no longer recognised in the IDE
- I have lost Intellisense in the project
- the Refactor options are not available
- `SimpleMembershipInitializer` has red squiggles indicating it can't
  be found

However the solution builds and appears to work without issue - I'd appreciate some pointers as to where to look to clear the above.

Comment: That happened to me several times. Pretty annoying thing. Restarting VS mostly helps, otherwise try uninstalling problematic packages and reinstall.

Comment: @vgSefa Closing doesn't help at all unfortunately, that';s the issue I'm afraid I'm not sure which packages are actually causing the problems, I was looking for some pointers as to how to track them down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this instance, it has happened a few times since and simply unloading the project and reloading it has resolved the issue every time